# App delegate calling method repeatedly

Tags: ios, appdelegate

So I have my **AppDelegate** method trying to set an object in a **ViewController** method. My **AppDelegate** looks like this:

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
    //Grab a reference to the UISplitViewController
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    PatientDetailViewController* patientDetailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = patientDetailViewController;


    //Grab a reference to the masterviewcontroller and get the first patient in the list.
    UINavigationController *patientNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    PatientMasterTableViewController *patientMasterViewController = (PatientMasterTableViewController *)[patientNavController topViewController];

    Patient* firstPatient = [[patientMasterViewController patientArray] objectAtIndex:0];

    //Set it as the detailviews patient.
    [patientDetailViewController setPatient:firstPatient];

    //Set the detail's as the left's delegate.
    patientMasterViewController.delegate = patientDetailViewController;
    }

return YES;
}
```

and the method to set the object looks like this:

```
-(void)setPatient:(Patient *)patient
{

if (![self.patient isEqual:patient])
    {
    self.patient = patient;

    //Update the UI to reflect the new patient selected from the list.
    [self refreshUI];
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that the setPatient method will be called non stop until the program crashes and I have no idea why. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Yes, it's a classic infinite-loop. `self.patient = patient` is the same as calling `[self setPatient:patient]`

Comment: Have you implemented isEqual: for the Patient class? If not, that call may not be doing what you expect.

Comment: Good call by @jshier: While it is recommended (by Apple) to use the instanceVariable when initing properties, the above code should only be called one additional time. It is unlikely that the equality check achieves much though, apart from adding noise to your code.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
-(void)setPatient:(Patient *)patient
{
if (![self.patient isEqual:patient])
    {
    self.patient = patient;

    //Update the UI to reflect the new patient selected from the list.
    [self refreshUI];
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
-(void)setPatient:(Patient *)patient
{
    _patient = patient;
    [self refreshUI];
}
```

Comment: No, he is better of using the underlying instance variable to set the value.

Comment: @nickfalk, yeah I agree.